# RSA 2048 статичный приватный ключ

Tags: c#, шифрование, rsa

Сразу скажу, что проект учебный. Требуется создать механизм шифрования с помощью RSA 2048 и по сети передавать открытый ключ на сервер. С передачей сообщений проблем нет. Но я не совсем понимаю, как хранить приватный ключ так, чтобы не передавать его на сервер. Да, можно сохранить приватный ключ и на стороне клиента, и на стороне сервера, хранить его в каком-нибудь зашифрованном файле.

Но вопрос, тогда ведь и публичная же часть ключа будет статическая? Правильно ли я понимаю, что если сделать статический приватный ключ, то публичный ключ будем статический?

Comment: Приватный ключ по определению это секрет, который должен храниться пользователем в надёждном месте. Передавать приватный ключ на сервер -- простите, нонсенс: это как ключ от сейфа с деньгами выставить на всеобщее обозрение.

Comment: Насчет приватного ключа я понимаю. Вопрос в другом. У меня одно приложение шифрует данные и отправляет их другому приложению, которое уже дешифрует данные. Ключ асимметричного шифрования (имеется ввиду RSA) должен генерироваться приложением-отправителем и программе-получателю должна передаваться открытая часть ключа. Суть в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как можно, храня приватный ключ, гененрировать на его основе публичный ключ средствами C#.

Answer (score 1):

> Ключ асимметричного шифрования (имеется ввиду RSA) должен генерироваться приложением-отправителем и программе-получателю должна передаваться открытая часть ключа.

Вы не правильно понимаете алгоритм работы RSA. В асимметричном шифровании, у каждого абонента *(кстати абонентов может быть не два, а сколько угодно)* должна быть пара **своих ключей** - приватный и публичный. Приватные все держат при себе, а публичные выкладывают на сервер, или иной общедоступный кэш-ключей.

Теперь, если абонент(А) хочет отправить сообщение абоненту (В), он берёт из сервера публичный ключ абонента (В) и шифрует им своё сообщение. Данное сообщение сможет расшифровать лишь тот, у кого имеется приватный ключ, публичной парой которого было зашифровано послание. Это достигается за счёт того, что публичный ключ генерируется на основе приватного *(для этого есть специальные [математические формулы](https://thecode.media/asymmetric/)).*

> Таким образом, если в RSA два абонента хотят обмениваться сообщениями, то у каждого из них должна быть своя пара приватных и публичных ключей, иначе обмен получится односторонним.

На схеме ниже, комиcар (С) пытается отправить зашифрованное асимметричным ключом письмо, своей зазнобе (А). Для этого, он берёт её публичный ключ из кеша *(ну или запрашивает его напрямую, если кеша нет)*, и криптует полученным ключом свои данные. При этом ни приватный, ни публичный свой ключ он не использует – приватный нужен только для расшифровки входящих сообщений, а публичным ключом будут шифровать сообщения ему.

Теперь, не важно как *(голубем, или по каналам связи)* он отправляет письмо получателю, который расшифровывает его своим приватным ключом. Исходя из того, что оба ключа привязываются друг-к-другу на этапе их создания, расшифровать послание чужим приватным ключом не получится – нужна только конкретная пара.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы сгенерировать пару ключей RSA на программном уровне, можно воспользоваться [функцией](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgeneratekeypair) API `BCryptGenerateKeyPair()` из библиотеки Bcrypt.dll. Она создаёт пару привязанных друг-к-другу чистых ключей, свойства которым можно задать через `BCryptSetProperty()`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Проблема у меня теперь такая: сервер отправляет клиенту открытый ключ. Клиент ключ получает (это уже проверено) и успешно шифрует текст сообщения (тоже проверено), затем зашифрованный текст отправляет серверу. Сервер (помня, естественно, и публичный, и приватный ключи) пытается дешифровать сообщение, но выбрасывается ошибка "Плохие данные". И я не понимаю, почему. Ведь для шифрования вполне же достаточно иметь просто открытый ключ, насколько я понимаю. А для дешифровки уже нужен ещё и закрытый ключ.

Comment: Все, сам справился. Просто неправильно писал массив байтов. В общем, это ошибка не по алгоритму.